# How to change an action label in a chooser dialog dynamically?

Tags: android

My application is able to receive a simple data from other applications and from itself. I want to change the action label of my app in the chooser dialog dynamically when I send a share intent from my app. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: can you update your question with codes?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `LabeledIntent`. Here is the solution:

```
public void openChooser() {
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is text for sharing");
    email.setType("text/plain");

    List<ResolveInfo> candidates = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(email, 0);

    List<Intent> targets = new ArrayList<>();

    for(ResolveInfo candidate : candidates) {
        String name = candidate.activityInfo.name;
        String packageName = candidate.activityInfo.packageName;
        int icon = candidate.activityInfo.icon;

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));

        if(packageName.equals(getPackageName())) {
            intent = new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, "Your custom label", icon);
        }

        targets.add(intent);
    }

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(targets.remove(0), "Share");
    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targets.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Here is the proof:

[image: Proof that code above works]

Comment: The solution doubles all the icons.

Comment: Does it change the label?

Comment: No, it doesn't change the label. It adds a new icon for your app with the custom label.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. I have edited the answer with correct code.

Comment: It works, but there is a side effect - the last icon occupies a separate line. You can see it if you have not (4*i+1) icons.